# Keycloak - Blocking Terms and Conditions in both Manual and IDP registration flows

Tags: keycloak, registration, idp

I currently have a problem configuring my Keycloak instance. I successfully customized the registration form to display some required informed consent that the users should read and accept to complete the registration. I achieved this by adding a mandatory "accept all" radio button before the "email" and "password" input boxes.

[registration terms and conditions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OGmts.png)

At the same time I also wish to provide a registration flow through Facebook. The problem in this case is that the user is automatically registered without any chance to read the aforementioned agreement. I already tried customizing the default terms and conditions page offered by Keycloak, but the "decline" choice is not blocking for the registration process. In other words the terms and conditions are displayed when the user has already been created.

My questions are:

1. How should I add a custom blocking "agreement form" also for the registration through Facebook?
2. Should I also split the agreement from the part in the manual registration? If yes, why and how?